# Issues with tracking clicks on links using jQuery

Tags: jquery, href

I have the following code:

```
<a href="http://mydomain.com/link123" class="someClickEvent">Some Link</a>

$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('.someClickEvent').click(function() {
        var $deal_id = 0;
        var $position = 0;  

       var data = {
           deal_id : $deal_id,
           position : $position                                                              
       };        
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            data: data,
            url : '/ajax/trackBannerClick',
            success : function(data){
                return true;  
            }
        });             
    });
});
```

And, it seems that the click event doesn't finish completing before the user is sent to the new URL.  Is there a way to make sure the click event has finished prior to sending the user to the new URL? I'd rather not use window.location since it isn't SEO friendly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* that adding `async: false` might cause the script to wait for the Ajax to complete before calling the `success` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('.someClickEvent').click(function() {
        var $deal_id = 0;
        var $position = 0;  

       var data = {
           deal_id : $deal_id,
           position : $position                                                              
       };        
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            data: data,
            url : '/ajax/trackBannerClick',
            async : false,
            success : function(data){
                return true;  
            }
        });             
    });
});
```

Reference:

- [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: It seems this is working so far.  Going to test a bit more between browsers.

Comment: I've tested across multiple browsers and I can't find any issues with it.  I think this will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('.someClickEvent').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $deal_id = 0;
        var $position = 0;  
        var data = {
            deal_id : $deal_id,
            position : $position                                                              
    };        
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        data: data,
        url : '/ajax/trackBannerClick',
        success : function(data){
            window.document.href = $(this).attr('href');
            return true;  
        }
    });            
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(e){  
    $('.someClickEvent').click(function() {
        var $deal_id = 0;
        var $position = 0;  

        //change 1
        var target=jQuery(e.target).attr('href');
        e.preventDefault()

       var data = {
           deal_id : $deal_id,
           position : $position                                                              
       };        
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            data: data,
            url : '/ajax/trackBannerClick',
            success : function(data){

                //change2
                window.location=target;
                return true;  
            }
        });             
    });
});
```